# Conceptual Data Model match MySQL script?

Tags: mysql

Could someone tell me if my Conceptual Data Model (MCD) matches my MySQL script?

Can cardinality (1,4) exist?

***MCD:***

```
tbl1 ---(1,4)---(relation)---(1,1)---tbl2
```

***MySql Script:***

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(
    idTbl1    Int  Auto_increment  NOT NULL 
    [...]
    ,CONSTRAINT tbl1_PK PRIMARY KEY (idTbl1)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE tbl2(
    idTbl2    Int  Auto_increment  NOT NULL 
    [...]
    ,CONSTRAINT tbl2_PK PRIMARY KEY (idTbl2)
    ,CONSTRAINT tbl2_tbl1_FK FOREIGN KEY (idTbl1) REFERENCES tbl1(idTbl1)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could enfoce your (1,4) cardinality, eg.

```
create table tbl2
    (idTbl1  int references tbl1,
     Tbl2Id int check (Tbl2Id in (1,2,3,4)) enforced,
     constraint tbl2_PK primary key (idTbl1,Tbl2Id))
;
```

Comment: only with mysql 8.x

Comment: How it's work? Can you explain me , thx.

Comment: For each entry in tbl1, a maximum of four entries in tbl2 can be registered.  Beginning from a certain version of mysql 8, mysql will make sure only ids 1, 2, 3 and 4 get in.